# Weird issue when using the 'Add new Item' option to add a text file to my VS2008 project

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am trying to add a text file to my project. Not that it is important but I am using these text files to store SQL statements. My project reads the SQL statement then uses it to gather data.

I use the right-click context menu from the project explorer to 'Add a new item', then select text file from the menu, change the file name and click the 'Add' button.

A blank template is displayed and no matter what I type, and save, when I read the file I get 3 garbage characters at the beginning of the file. You cannot see them in the editor but if you view the file in a hex editor you can see them.

Before you ask, no, it is not my read routine that is creating the characters as I used an external edit to view the file and they're there. I think Visual Studio is putting them there.

Here is what the text looks like in a HEX editor:

ï»¿SELECT ...etc..

^^^
Which doesn't bode well for my SQL statement.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're just a UTF-8 [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). They're three *bytes*, but a single *character*.

Whether they're a problem for you will depend on how your project reads the file. IIRC, `StreamReader` will read and strip it, so you should be okay.

When you save the file, you can go to "File / Advanced Save Options" and select an encoding of

> Unicode (UTF-8 without signature)

to avoid the BOM. It would probably be best to just change your code to cope though.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the tip, unfortunately I am using VS2008 to maintain legacy ASP classic. I'm not entirely sure how to do this using the Scripting.FileSystemObject object.

Comment: @carny666: Sounds like you probably just want to change how the file is saved then, as per the second half of my answer.

Comment: @JohnSkeet I do apologize, I didn't realize I had to click the check mark to accept an answer on SO.